# Age based problem

Tags: ratio

Ajay’s age was 4 times the age of his son when Ajay was as old as his daughter is now. If his son is now half as old as the daughter, find the ratio of the present ages of Ajay and his daughter.

Comment: Maybe you can find inspiration in this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2904760/age-based-word-problem/2904765#2904765

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Denote Ajay, his son and daughter's ages by **a,s and d**
You get following equations:

Ajay was as old as his daughter **(a-d)** years ago. Then, his son was **(s-(a-d))** years 
old.

From first statement:
**(a-d) years ago, a was 4 times s.**
$$a-(a-d)=4(s-(a-d))$$

Second statement is quite simple:
**s is half of d today.** $$s=\frac d2$$
$s=\frac d2$ means $d=2s$
put $d=2s$ in second equation:
$$d=4(s-a+d)$$ $$2s=4(s-a+2s)$$ $$2s=4(3s-a)$$ $$2s=12s-4a$$ $$s=6s-2a$$ $$2a=5s$$ $$\frac a s =\frac 52$$

put $s=\frac d2$ finally: $$\frac {2a}{d}=\frac 5 2$$

> So, $$\frac a d= \frac 5 4$$  Ratio of ages of Ajay and his daughter is $$5:4$$

Comment: So the ratio is !

Comment: 5:2 its quite simple. just solve simultaneous equations

Comment: wait i'll add it to my solution

Comment: @Bharadwaj got it now?

Comment: @Bharadwaj note: $5:2$ was for ajay and son. $5:4$ is for ajay and daughter.